# raw socket reads from a particular port without impacting application traffic

Tags: c, linux, tcp

From my basic socket understanding, sockets have a buffer, from which application can read the data received from a NIC. Once the application reads the data from the buffer, the data is gone from buffer perspective. But the sniffers like wireshark, are able to copy the packet? How can they read packet from a particular port and still the application manages to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Raw socket sniffs from `Ethernet`, it do not fetch from port, but accepts all `Unicast`/`Multicast` message. Because data to any port go from Ethernet layer.

Wireshark uses `WinPcap` drives, which sniffs data from Ethernet layer.

Comment: but only a single packet is received. how do they read the packet, without impacting the packet flow by OS to the application

Comment: @Jimm Sniffing does not impact any packet, it just watch data to and fro. For example, Wireshark sniffs all packets but it will not make any trouble to reach to your application.